Thread index within TParallel.For when using TThreadPool
Inspired by CUDA, I would like to identify the index of each thread of a TThreadPool when used within a TParallel.For.
Consider the following non-compiling code:
var
  v: Array of Integer;
  APool: TThreadPool;
begin
    APool:= TThreadPool.Create;
    APool.SetMinWorkerThreads(10);
    APool.SetMaxWorkerThreads(10);

    SetLength(v, 10);

    TParallel.For(0, 9, procedure(i: Integer)
     begin
      v[i]:= APool.ThreadID; // Property ThreadId DOES NOT EXIST!
     end, APool);
end;

How do I get the integer array v to store the index of the thread of the threadpool that has done the work? Of course, because there are 10 threads in the pool, the numbers in the array should range between 0 .. 9.

You can always use TThread.Current to get the current thread that executes particular code and then you can use ThreadID to retrieve its ID.
Note: If you run this code as-is, it is very likely that it will run so fast that all work will be executed on one thread, so all thread IDs will be the same.
TParallel.For(0, 9, procedure(i: Integer)
 begin
  v[i]:= TThread.Current.ThreadID;
 end, APool);


Thanks for your input. I tested your suggestions found that: (1) indeed all work is run by a single thread. Do you have any idea how I could make sure that each task is run a different thread? Also, (2) the ThreadID values do not range between 0 and 9. Indeed, ThreadID values seem to be system wide ID (e.g. 15023), and not an index within the thread pool. Do you have any idea how I could get the index of the thread within the thread pool?

If your thread will do some actual work besides just reading ThreadID, then it will most likely run on the different thread. But that does not mean that all tasks will run on different threads and you cannot get the thread index. If your requirements are that each task must run on separate dedicated thread, then you should create your custom thread class and use that. You cannot use System.Threading in that case.

thank you very much for your reply. It indeed seems that TParallel.For will not work for me, and that I will have to create my own thread class.
